# Local co-op on PC with separate Steam accounts

Tags: pit-people

Took a bit, but I found local Steam co-op by going to the town's character select screen and clicking F2 and "A" on a second controller, but the game prompts to choose another slot in the primary Steam account's save file. Is there a way to sign in with a second Steam account for the second player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not be signed in two different Steam accounts at the same time on the same device.